# Using oclif in vscode, how to resolve "The inferred type of 'flags' cannot be named without a reference to..." problem?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, oclif

I am building a CLI utility using oclif, writing it in Typescript.

Inside vscode all of the generated command files are giving me an error that says

> The inferred type of 'flags' cannot be named without a reference to '../../../../../../Projects/bag-man/tmp/mynewcli/node_modules/@oclif/parser/lib/flags'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.

The extra frustrating part is that in some files it repeats the error 4 times for the same instance (ie there is only a single red underline in the whole file, but the "Problems" view lists the same problem 4 times.)

This is one of the files which shows it 4 times - this is exactly what oclif generates for a command file. The problem is found on line 12 on `flags`.

```
import {Command, flags} from '@oclif/command'

export default class Hello extends Command {
  static description = 'describe the command here'

  static examples = [
    `$ mynewcli hello
hello world from ./src/hello.ts!
`,
  ]

  static flags = {
    help: flags.help({char: 'h'}),
    // flag with a value (-n, --name=VALUE)
    name: flags.string({char: 'n', description: 'name to print'}),
    // flag with no value (-f, --force)
    force: flags.boolean({char: 'f'}),
  }

  static args = [{name: 'file'}]

  async run() {
    const {args, flags} = this.parse(Hello)

    const name = flags.name ?? 'world'
    this.log(`hello ${name} from ./src/commands/hello.ts`)
    if (args.file && flags.force) {
      this.log(`you input --force and --file: ${args.file}`)
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on what I need to modify, either in the code or in my vscode linter settings, to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not looked in to why, but setting `"declaration": false` in your `tsconfig.json` fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by adding the type to the `flags` field.
For example:

```js
static flags : flags.Input<any> = {
  // your flags...
}
```